# JTextArea how to find column count / row width?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm looking for a way to get the number of characters that can appear in a row in a `JTextArea`.

I tried using `getColumns()` but this returned 0:

```
jTextArea.getColumns();
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? I need it so that I can display data in fixed width columns, so I need the number of characters that can fit in a row in order to calculate this.

Comment: Why you are not using JTable?

Comment: Does that text area use a mono spaced font?

Comment: *"I need it so that I can display data in fixed width columns"* A `JTable` as suggested by Omore would probably be best for this, though an HTML aware component such as a `JLabel` or a `JEditorPane` could display an HTML `table`..

Comment: I am writing a terminal emulator, so the application is text based. I don't think JTable would be appropriate (correct me if I'm wrong), I'm emulating the function of 'ls' in a Linux terminal and I want to display the results in a column style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify number of rows and columns when creating JTextArea, it default the rows and columns to zero. This mode allows the JTextArea to expand/contract according to available space for itself and actual number of letters shown in a line etc can be adjusted.

In the default mode, the number of letters that would fit in a line will depend on the current dimension of the component, the line wrapping style (word boundary or character boundary) and the font used.

If you cannot set the row, columns in the JTextArea then you can probably use `javax.swing.JTextArea.getColumnWidth()` to get the size of one character and use the current width of the component to get approximate number of letters that will fit in a line.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I'll use the constructor to specify the rows and columns

Comment: `want to display the results in a column style` - You will also need to use a Monospaced font so each character takes the same width..